# Different user can access different feature

Tags: software-development, product-management, project-management-style

I have already developed website in nodejs and MySQL

Now my client wants to add payment functionality. We have lots of features in the website like:-

1) Copy

2) Save

3) Delete

4) Groups

5) Read,  and many more.

We have a different package for each feature. I am not sure how to manage this? Can anyone tell me what will be the best approach to do this?

Comment: Are you asking for a design? Or for PjM advice. If the former it's off topic, if the latter we need more info on your team and structure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want PjM advice (as per your tags):

What you are describing is called a *change request*.

You need to:

- Define exactly what the client wants - this is documented as a *change request* that the client signs off on.
- Decide how to price it
- Write a Technical Spec including the design changes and the GUI elements needed.

  - Review existing design to see what else will be affected and include it in the Technical Spec.
- Figure out the tasks, create a schedule and then track, implement, test and ship.